# Normal of a 3D tangent

Tags: computational-geometry, curve, normals

So I have 3 points in a 3D space with a curve passing through the points. I have found the tangent of the point in the middle by averaging the two points either side of it, but I want to find the Normal at the point in the middle. How would I do this without knowing the equation of the line?

`P(1) = (0,1,0)
P(2) = (2,2,2)
p(3) = (4,4,4)

Tangent at P(2) = (4,3,4)`

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is the wrong forum for this question

Comment: There is infinite amount of various curves through these points, so clarification is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A = P2 - P1 ... vector between 2 points on the curve (one is the middle point .. P2)

- normal = A x tangent
- but as MBo pointed out there are infinite number of normals (all are perpendicular to the curve lying  on the same plane)
- above equation gives one perpendicular to curve and to that A vector

Comment: one  might expect the normal to lie in the plane formed by the points, which you will get with one more cross : ( a x tangent ) x tangent.  (of course as said there is no unique answer.. )